# iTunes Update Logic

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

I'm on charge of a large application for iPad (+400mb), being most of the weight in the content (PDFs and images). I've already uploaded a version.

My question is: if I upload an **update** (from 1.0 to 1.1) and I **only change a PDF** in the bundle (3mb), does the user -that already has the app- will download the entire app again (+400mb) or just the change in the bundle (3mb)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a user will need to re-download the entire app.

Comment: To elaborate though - you could implement a cloud-based file storage solution, eg Amazon S3, and point your app to a folder of your PDFs in the cloud. This would save a user needing to re-download your app each time a document changes.

Comment: Tank you Luke! Yeap, it seems that I'll have to implement something there.